# Norm of $\sum_{n=2018}^\infty x_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let's consider operator T:

$$T : c_{00} \ni x_n \rightarrow \sum_{n=2018}^\infty x_n$$

With norm

$$\|x_n\| = (\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x_n|^{2019})^\frac{1}{2019}$$

I want to check whether $T$ is bounded and after that calculate its norm.

**My work so far**

I was trying to somehow bound $|T(x_n)|$ but I couldn't find any reasonable bound. My only idea as that since $x_n \in c_{00}$ then $\exists_{n_0} \forall_{n \ge n_0} x_n = 0$, so

$$|T(x_n)| = |\sum_{n=2018}^{n_0} x_n|\le \sum_{n=2018}^{n_0} |x_n| \le \sum_{n=2018}^{n_0}\|x_n\| = \|x_n\|\sum_{n=2018}^{n_0}1 = \|x_n\| \cdot (n_0 - 2018 + 1)$$

and this bound is quite good, but the problem is that it's $n_0$ dependent (it means that it's dependent of the moment when $x_n$ is constructed with only zeroes, so it's $x_n$ dependent).

Could you please give me a hint whether this functional can be bounded but not using $x_n$ dependent objects?

Comment: Where is the question from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This map is not bounded. Consider the sequences $(0,0,...,\frac 1 n, 
\frac  1{n+1},...,\frac 1{n+m},0,0...)$. The norms of these vectors are bounded since $\sum_k \frac 1 {k^{p}} <\infty$ where $p=2019$. If T is a bounded opeator then (it maps norm bounded sets to bounded sets of real numbers so) $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{n+m} \frac 1k $ would be bounded but this is not true.